# kivy: My screenmanager code is not working with scrollview

Tags: android, uiscrollview, kivy

Trying to get my kivy to work with screenmanager and scrollview. I cannot see why it is not working. If I remove the scrollview and just keep it as a simple box and button (like screen 2 in code) it works fine. As soon as I try to add the scroll view with buttons all I get is a blank screen.

Can somebody help point out my mistake. I am new to kivy.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from urllib import urlopen
from re import findall, MULTILINE, sub

heading = []
date = []
id_ref = []

URL_list = 'web_site_here.xml'

O_WL = urlopen(URL_list).read()


class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenOne, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Buttonlayout = GridLayout(orientation='vertical',cols=1, spacing=2, size_hint_y=None)
        Buttonlayout.bind(minimum_height=Buttonlayout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(len(id_ref)):
            btn = Button(text=heading[i], size_hint_y=None, height=80,text_size=(350,None),font_size='12sp')
            btn.bind(on_press=(lambda a:self.changer()))
            Buttonlayout.add_widget(btn)
        root = ScrollView()
        root.add_widget(Buttonlayout)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'story_screen'

class ScreenTwo(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenTwo,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        story_box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        story_heading = Label(text="testing")
        back = Button(text="Back",size_hint_y=None, size_y=50)
        back.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        story_box.add_widget(story_heading)
        story_box.add_widget(back)
        self.add_widget(story_box)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'but_screen'

class TestApp(App):

    O_WL = urlopen(URL_list).read()

    id_ex = findall('<id>(.*)</id>',O_WL)
    for i in id_ex:
        id_ref.extend([i])  

    head_ex = findall('<headline>(.*)</headline>',O_WL)
    for i in head_ex:
        heading.extend([i])
    date_ex = findall('<modifiedDate>(.*)</modifiedDate>',O_WL)
    for i in date_ex:
        date.extend([i]) 

    def build(self):
        my_screenmanager = ScreenManager()
        screen1 = ScreenOne(name='but_screen')
        screen2 = ScreenTwo(name='story_screen')
        my_screenmanager.add_widget(but_screen)
        my_screenmanager.add_widget(story_screen)
        return my_screenmanager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need, at least, to add your `root` in your `ScreenOne`

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        ...
        root = ScrollView()
        root.add_widget(Buttonlayout)
        self.add_widget(root)
```

Comment: It was that simple huh? *Face palm* You my friend are a champion. Have 1000 internets as a gift.

Comment: @GenGen I am not able to work it out..... I have a separate .kv file..... can you please help?

Comment: It gives out this error 
"File "C:\Users\DELL-E7470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 139, in add_widget
     pos_hint=self._trigger_layout)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 419, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind
 AssertionError: None is not callable"